# I do not understant how this piece of code works

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am doing a school project and we are learning how to read text files and search them. Can you please help me to understand the following code. I know that the first section asks the user to input the team name they want to search and this is stored as a variable and then the file is opened. However, I don't understand the bold code (between the stars). It would be helpful if someone could explain each line of the bold code (between the stars). Thanks in advance.

```
Console.Write("Enter the team name:")
                findname = Console.ReadLine()
                FileOpen(1, "TeamdataFile.txt", OpenMode.Input)

                **Do
                    Input(1, teamname)
                    Input(1, townname)
                    Input(1, coachname)
                    Input(1, phone)
                    If teamname.ToLower = findname.ToLower Then
                        Console.WriteLine("Team: {0}, from {1}, coach: {2}, contact: {3}", teamname, townname, coachname, phone)
                        foundresult = True
                    End If
                Loop Until EOF(1)**
                FileClose(1)
```

Comment: the code just reads records from a file and checks if the record "teamname" equals to your "findname" variable.. if it does, it echoes something on the console and sets a boolean variable "foundresult" to true.. that's pretty much it

Comment: And The `ToLower` just guarantees that the string comparison will not be case-sensitive (it will find a match even if case is different). ....   and `EOF` means End Of File.  This means it runs the code over and over, once per line of text in the file, until the end of the file

Comment: Oh dear. It's like they don't even care about teaching marketable skills. Yes you *can* use functions like `FileOpen` to do I/O, but they were only ever intended for backwards compatibility with pre-.NET VB. So they're teaching you ways to do things that won't translate across to other .NET languages if you ever need to switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this might help (I've commented all those lines you need):

```
**Do  ' start the loop
    Input(1, teamname)  ' read the data record from file and store it into variable teamname
    Input(1, townname)  ' read the data record from file and store it into variable townname
    Input(1, coachname)  ' read the data record from file and store it into variable coachname
    Input(1, phone)  ' read the data record from file and store it into variable phonename
    If teamname.ToLower = findname.ToLower Then  ' if findname equals teamname
        Console.WriteLine("Team: {0}, from {1}, coach: {2}, contact: {3}", teamname, townname, coachname, phone)  ' write something on the console
        foundresult = True  ' set some boolean variable to true
    End If
Loop Until EOF(1)**  ' continue the loop until you read the entire file
```